# Problemas na implementação da autenticação do JWT com NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, autenticação, jwt, dapper

Olá, estou com dificuldades em implementar o JWT na minha API, eu pesquisei e olhei vários tutoriais sobre o assunto e notei que utilizam o Identity, porem eu uso o Dapper para poder verificar se o usuário existe no Banco de Dados e após eu gero o token com o nome e e-mail. O meu problema (eu acho) que está na hora de enviar o token, pois sempre tenho o retorno 401 e não consigo achar nada de errado.

Já tentei passar o Token na aba Auth do Insomnia conforme apontado pelo mouse do print. Já tentei passar no Header conforme o print também. até agora não tive sucesso, vou por meus códigos abaixo. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

[image: Token na aba de autenticação]

[image: Token na aba de Header]

```
public class Startup {

  // Properties
  public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

  // Constructor
  public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
    this.Configuration = configuration;
  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddCors();
    services.AddControllers();

    var jwtToken = new JwtToken();
    this.Configuration.GetSection("JwtToken").Bind(jwtToken);
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtToken.key);
  
    services.AddAuthentication(x => {
      x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer(x => {
      // x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
      x.SaveToken = true;
      x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidAudiences = jwtToken.audiences,
        ValidIssuers = jwtToken.issuers,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
      };
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    services.AddMapperBLL();
  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      app.UseSwagger();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
      endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
  }
```

Classe que gera o Token e é chamada na controller.

```
public static class TokenService {
  public static UserResponse GenerateToken(this UserResponse infoUser, JwtToken jwtToken) {
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var dtExpires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(decimal.ToDouble(jwtToken.expireMinutes));
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtToken.key); 

    var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor {
      Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, infoUser.nmUser),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, infoUser.email)
        // new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user.Role.ToString()")
      }),
      Expires = dtExpires,
      SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512)
    };

    var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    infoUser.dtExpire = dtExpires;
    infoUser.token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

    return infoUser;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, após mais alguns debugs e uma boa noite de sono, eu consegui descobrir o problema. Percebi que na geração do token eu não estava passando as informações de **Issuer** e **Audience** mas estava validando as informações na classe **startup**. É isso pessoal, se alguém tiver mais alguma observação a fazer do meu código, fique a vontade para comentar que eu verei se enquadra na minha situação.

Obrigado.